# I recently enrolled in masters in AI after doing my bachelor in CS, I'm overwhelmed how to start research

Tags: publications, research-process, journals, masters, conference

So as someone who started  aiming for PhD and enrolled in masters , I'm really confused with how someone could move in the AI/ML research domain... I see outstanding papers published round the clock and it really makes me feel how anything I would do would even match the lowest standard worthy of publishing, not to mention the single biggest problem I don't have a problem in hand.

It increasingly looks like to me that I'll publish a review paper instead because I feel I'm decent enough in doing literature review (which really helped me with previous publications), but it feels like a shortcut, that I am not doing actual research and I am nowhere good to warrant a publishing.

PS I had some experience of publishing papers in my bachelor and know the general process followed in the academic writing, but these were often papers I really think were not worthy enough to be published. They had stemmed out of mostly the project I was involved in undergraduate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR. Search this forum, and beyond, for *impostor syndrome*: What you're experiencing is perfectly normal.**

At masters-level, you're just entering the <strike>amphitheatre</strike> arena. Of course everyone looks better, you haven't started yet. *I see outstanding papers published round the clock*, that's great! You're looking in the right places, finding the best stuff. *It really makes me feel how anything I would do would even match the lowest standard worthy of publishing*, that's impostor syndrome. Hang around, absorb the knowledge, learn how to compete.

*[N]ot to mention the single biggest problem I don't have a problem in hand*, many students get handed problems by their advisors, only later do they identify their own problems.

Look in the mirror, ask yourself, *do I want to do research?* If the answer is *yes*, go learn how to do it. Don't worry about not being able today.

Comment: Your comment really helped me .. Thank you its really reassuring ... I think I m trying to think large all of a sudden , maybe taking baby concrete steps eventually will help me